# Get text from page with selenium and python if website change location of text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I am trying to get last results from a specific table called  "Last matches" in this [Webpage](https://s5.sir.sportradar.com/sports4africa/en/1/season/80526/headtohead/334075/340986/match/27195664)

For exemple the result of the first meeting by `xpath` is like this:

```
int1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"sr-container\"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[7]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/div/div[2]").get_attribute("innerText")
```

For second meeting is like this:

```
int2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"sr-container\"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[7]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]/div/div[2]").get_attribute("innerText")
```

If the shape of the webpage is like the one i posted i can extract all results from that table, my problem is when i have a meeting like this [Link](https://s5.sir.sportradar.com/sports4africa/en/1/season/82128/headtohead/613958/33714/match/27197856) the `xpath` is not the same and nothing can work

Is there a better way to locate this `Last Matches table` and extract data even if the shape of the page is not the same?

Help is appreciated, thanks to all of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more good option is to use `ancestor` in xpath. I bound the main locator to the table name, it would be more reliable.

Using it you can find other locators and their text. Just put them to the loop with correct paths.
In the child xpath `.//td` means a direct child of the main locator with element name `td.`

**My solution:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


url = 'https://s5.sir.sportradar.com/sports4africa/en/1/season/80526/headtohead/334075/340986/match/27195664'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//strong[text()='Last matches']/ancestor::div[6]//tbody/tr")))
rows= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//strong[text()='Last matches']/ancestor::div[6]//tbody/tr")
output = []
for res in rows:
    score = res.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[5]//div[@class=' no-wrap']").get_attribute("innerText")
    output.append(score)
print(output)
```

**Output:**
First [link](https://s5.sir.sportradar.com/sports4africa/en/1/season/80526/headtohead/334075/340986/match/27195664):
['0:4', '3:4', '2:2', '0:1', '3:0', '2:2', '0:4', '1:0', '2:1', '1:1', '1:2', '2:4']

Second [link](https://s5.sir.sportradar.com/sports4africa/en/1/season/82128/headtohead/613958/33714/match/27197856):
['2:0', '2:1', '0:2', '0:0', '4:2', '1:0', '3:0', '1:1', '1:0', '2:1', '1:1', '0:8']

**Update:**
The fastest way to swap scores I could do is with getting two scores separately, placing them in a separate lists and swapping using `zip`.
The results are two lists of tuples.

```
first_score = []
second_score = []
for res in rows:
    first = res.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[5]//div[@class=' no-wrap']/div[1]").get_attribute("innerText")
    first_score.append(first)
    second = res.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[5]//div[@class=' no-wrap']/div[3]").get_attribute("innerText")
    second_score.append(second)
first_list = list(zip(first_score, second_score))
second_list = list(zip(second_score, first_score))
print(first_list)
print(second_list)
```

The results are two lists of tuples.

```
[('0', '4'), ('3', '4'), ('2', '2'), ('0', '1'), ('3', '0'), ('2', '2'), ('0', '4'), ('1', '0'), ('2', '1'), ('1', '1'), ('1', '2'), ('2', '4')]
[('4', '0'), ('4', '3'), ('2', '2'), ('1', '0'), ('0', '3'), ('2', '2'), ('4', '0'), ('0', '1'), ('1', '2'), ('1', '1'), ('2', '1'), ('4', '2')]
```

There are more effective ways to do it, but I'd suggest to ask a separate question for it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how is it possible to get the results of both teams separatly?

Comment: To get both teams names and scor` use locator for `score`: `.//td[5]//div[@class='row flex-items-xs-middle']` But you'll need to split result to get rid of \n. Without split the result be be like: `['CF America\n0:4\nTigres UANL', 'Guadalajara\n3:4\nTigres UANL', 'Tigres UANL\n2:2\nMazatlan', 'Tijuana\n0:1\nTigres UANL', 'Tigres UANL\n3:0\nCruz Azul', 'Monterrey\n2:2\nTigres UANL', 'CF America\n0:4\nTigres UANL', 'Puebla FC\n1:0\nCF America', 'CF America\n2:1\nCruz Azul', 'Monterrey\n1:1\nCF America', 'Santos Laguna\n1:2\nCF America', 'CF America\n2:4\nGuadalajara']
`

Comment: What kind of output are you expecting? Read how to split a list to get rid of \n, and how to print the result. It should be easy. Write if you will not be able to do it.

Comment: I mean last results of home team, and last results of away team separatly, every results of a team in a list separatly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232185/discussion-between-vitaliis-and-hamita).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible you have to introduce xpath axes :

**XPATH :**

```
//strong[text()='Last matches']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'component-header no-margin')]/../following-sibling::div[1]/descendant::table/descendant::td[5]/div/child::div[2]/div
```

read more about xpath axes [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)

Answer (score 1):

This was tested against both of your links...

The issue is there are 2 separate tables in the HTML (left and right) for `Last matches`.  In order to get all of the results, you need to iterate over both of them.  I used [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) below to make the xpath dynamic, since the xPath for both tables are exactly the same aside from one number between the brackets `[]`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://s5.sir.sportradar.com/sports4africa/en/1/season/82128/headtohead/613958/33714/match/27197856")

tables = [1,2]
results = []
for table in tables:
    last_match_table = f"(//table[@class='table'])[{table}]//tbody/tr"
    scores = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,(last_match_table))))
    for score in scores:
        results.append(score.get_attribute("innerText"))

for row in results:
    text_split = row.split()
    final = ' '.join(text_split[4:])
    print(final)
```

Note that I also used a much more generic xPath.  When changes happen in the DOM (as you saw) this won't be affected.  There are 4 tables on that page given this path `//table[@class='table']`, 2 for `Last matches` and 2 for `Next matches`, so we only want to target the first 2, hence iterating over the list `tables = [1,2]` dynamically to populate the xPaths

Results:

```
Bolivar 2:0 CD Real Tomayapo
CD Real Tomayapo 2:1 Blooming
Guabira 0:2 CD Real Tomayapo
CD Real Tomayapo 0:0 Real Potosi
Royal Pari 4:2 CD Real Tomayapo
CD Real Tomayapo 1:0 Always Ready
Aurora 3:0 Independiente Petrolero
Aurora 1:1 Bolivar
Blooming 1:0 Aurora
Aurora 2:1 Guabira
Real Potosi 1:1 Aurora
Aurora 0:8 Royal Pari
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how is it possible to get the results of both teams separatly?

Comment: I just updated my answer.   You could get more detailed and technical if you wanted, but that at least gives you a winner/loser and score.  if you wanted more than that you'd have to get into some complicated slicing, probably look for the elements differently etc..

Comment: Thank you, but how it's possible to store results in two separate lists, first list for home team and second list for away team, just the reslt of the matches, without team name

Comment: No offense, but Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.  Your questions are straying further and further from your original post. @vitaliis and I have already given you plenty of code to get you started.  I suggest you go back, give it an honest effort, and if you still are struggling then create a new post/question with your updated code and people can help.  As it is now, your original code and question have nothing to do with what you are asking for now.